# Exporting matplotlib plot to holoviews

Tags: python, matplotlib, holoviews

I'm using a library called [GPy](http://pythonhosted.org/GPy/index.html) to fit a Gaussian process model and plot the output. The library has it's own plotting functionality, and returns a matplotlib figure.

I'd like to use this output in a holoviews element, as part of a [dynamic map](http://holoviews.org/Tutorials/Dynamic_Map.html). This feels like it should be possible, but I can't find a good way to do it.

I had wondered about reading the matplotlib figure into a numpy image array and sending this to a holoviews Raster element - but the only way to do this seems to be saving the figure to a file, which does not seem a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! At the point where you define holoviews elements, they are still backend-agnostic. Matplotlib etc. only come into play when they are actually rendered. Hence no, you cannot take a matplotlib figure as such and pipe that into a holoviews element.

Hence you have two options:

1. Extract the data from the matplotlib figure in some way, or get hold of those data from GPy in some other way, and create a holoviews element from that, or
2. Use the code that generates the matplotlib figure in a panel (https://panel.pyviz.org) app.

Number 2 is closer to what you are probably imagining but without a minimal working example I cannot say much more.